# Trying to disable Send button when there are errors

Tags: reactjs, forms, use-state

I have this form in a react-redux component.
The problem is that I’m trying to make the Send button disabled when the input.trim() is empty.
It is not behaving as expected.
If I type something, the button remains disabled,

```
export default function TodoInput() {
const [todoText, setTodoText] = React.useState('');
const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState('');
const dispatch = useDispatch()

function validate(text) {
    text.trim()
    return (text.length !== 0 ? 'Error' : '')
}

function handleInputChange(e) {
    setTodoText((e.target.value).trim())
    setErrors(validate(e.target.value));
}

function submitButton() {
    if (errors.length !== 0)
        return <input type="submit" onSubmit={onSubmit} className="btn btn-primary mx-2" disabled/>
    else
        return <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mx-2"/>
}

function onSubmit() {
    dispatch(todoAdded(todoText))
}

return (
    <div>
        <div className="row m-2">
            <form className={style.todoForm} 
                onSubmit={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault(); // the default behavior is to refresh the whole window
                    onSubmit(todoText);
                    setTodoText('')
            }}>
                <input type="text" 
                    className="col form-control"
                    placeholder="Todo Text..."
                    name="todoText" 
                    value={todoText} 
                    onChange={handleInputChange} 
                />
                {submitButton()}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

What could it be?

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: I spotted an error, validate was wrong, is was sending an error when there wasn´t any error. And, the first time there's an error already, text===''

Comment: im not sure if i understand what do you need. do you want to avoid user to type only spaces? If user type any character the button must be clickeable?